# Convention file names in MVC4

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage

I'm reading this [guide](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/#create-table) for how to use Azure table for data storage. But in this guide doesn't really tell you in which folder you should save the files. So I wonder if there's some up to date guide which tells you that, or if someone could show or explain which folder the codes goes into?

For example should I store this code into the model folder?

```
public class CustomerEntity : TableServiceEntity
{
    public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = lastName;
        this.RowKey = firstName;
    }

    public CustomerEntity() { }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create different project for everything. Since your example contains an entity, I will place it in a project called 'Entities' that I can use across the application. Similarly I create a 'ViewModels' project containing viewmodels, a 'WebUI' project containing the MVC application, etc.

You could place all your code in one project (what folder doesn't really matter), but it's easier to share and re-use code if you place it in different assemblies.

Comment: I'm still unsure how to do it. So you suggest I make a new project with the files containing access to that entity? Wouldn't that why generate lots of projects. If I for example have 10+ different entities?

Comment: Wait what? No. You have one 'code library' project that just contains all your entities (so these little classes that represent a database table).

Answer (score 0):

The guide instructs how to use Azure table storage. The same code can be used in an MVC application, a Web Forms application, a WPF application, and so on. So as pointed out by Leon, the best practice in a real world solution is to create a class library project as the data access layer. Then it can be reused by multiple projects.

But if you only need to access table storage in a single MVC application, it is fine to just put the code in the MVC project. Usually you put it under the Models folder.